# Dynamic data, COUNTIFS formula value 0

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have started creating my first dinamic report, but I bumped into some problems.

I have a source sheet with project group data in Column Z and month-year data in Column AO. My goal is to generate a report table that displays the count of product types for each unique project group and month-year combination.

Steps Taken:

1. I've successfully extracted unique project groups in Column A:

```
=UNIQUE(IMPORTRANGE(
   "URL", "Form Responses 1!Z2:Z")))
```

2. I've obtained unique month-year combinations in Column B:

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(IMPORTRANGE(
   "URL", "Form Responses 1!AO2:AO"),
   "MMMM YYYY")))
```

The issue is,  however, when I attempt to calculate the counts using the formula

```
=COUNTIFS(
  IMPORTRANGE(
   "URL", "Form Responses 1!Z:Z"),$A2,
  IMPORTRANGE(
   "URL", "Form Responses 1!AO:AO"),
     TEXT(B$1, "MMMM YYYY"))
```

The resulting count is consistently 0.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Questions should include all the required details to reproduce the problem. To make this easier, you could try to reproduce the problem using a single spreadsheet. Descript the relevant parts of the spreadsheet, including the spreadsheet locale, and add some sample data, including the expected result. Add links to the most relevant questions and briefly explain why they don't meet your needs.